# Should you include the ratio of two variables in survival analysis?

Tags: regression, survival, interaction, regression-coefficients, ratio

Suppose I have the following (Rossi recidivism) dataset:

```
     week  arrest  fin  age  race  wexp  mar  paro  prio
0      20       1    0   27     1     0    0     1     3
1      17       1    0   18     1     0    0     1     8
2      25       1    0   19     0     1    0     1    13
3      52       0    1   23     1     1    1     1     1
```

The *week* column is the duration, the *arrest* column denotes if the event (a re-arrest) occurred, and the other columns represent variables we wish to regress against.

**Is there a theoretical basis for or against including the ratio of two variables?** For example, *age*/*prio*would be the individual's age divided by the number of prior arrests.

From my experience, ratio variables do not produce intuitive results. For example, by setting a new event column, *interactions_with_police*, which is correlated with the *arrest* column, the effect of *age* is in the same direction for both event columns. That is, the coefficients of *age* are either both positive or both negative. This is the same for *prio*. However, the effect of *age*/*prio* are in opposite directions (positive coefficient for *arrest* and negative for *interactions_with_police* or vice-versa).

Comment: This seems like a very open-ended question that will be hard to answer. Some very useful variables are inherently ratios (moles per liter for chemical concentrations, miles per gallon for automobile efficiency, etc.) Is there some particular type of ratio that you are questioning? Please edit the question to make your specific issues clearer, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Sorry, there is not a particular type of ratio. For chemical concentrations, would you include moles? litres? and moles per litre? Similarly, for automobile efficiency, would you include miles? gallons? and miles per gallon? In that case, wouldn't the ratio variable be the *interesting* variable? Maybe you can help me re-word my question.

Comment: Whether to include numerator and denominator separately or as a ratio depends on the question that's being asked. This is related to the general distinction between [intensive and extensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties). Sometimes an intensive property is useful, sometimes you need an extensive property. In a survival model, do you care about the concentration of a drug that's being infused today (mole/liter), or to a patient's cumulative dosing over time since study start (moles)? Either, in principle, might be evaluated.

Comment: @EdM Well, I guess this is almost a variable selection question. I used *common sense* to decide on which variables to include. For example, we expect older individuals to be less at risk of re-arrests and those with more priors to be more at risk—we should include both. With *age/prio*, it is not intuitive how that would influence re-arrests—we should not include. My PI disagrees. They think that we should test as many variables as possible and then try to explain the results, and if we cannot come up with an explanation, we discard the variable. What do you think?

Comment: You say: "My PI disagrees. They think that we should test as many variables as possible and then try to explain the results, and if we cannot come up with an explanation, we discard the variable." It sounds like there is a particular situation at hand rather than the classic Rossi data. It might help to edit the question to be more specific about the particular disagreement at hand. There is something to be said for including as many predictors as reasonable without overfitting a model, but it's hard to provide a one-size-fits all answer. Providing more details _in the question_ would help.

Comment: @EdM That is the situation. I am not using the real dataset because it is confidential. I am running survival analysis; my PI *thinks* of ratios; I run the ratios, and then I find the result unintuitive. The example I have provided is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

In these data, `age/prio` might seem hard to interpret. It has a particular problem if `prio = 0`, so I would avoid it.

In the other direction, `prio/age`, it has a clear and useful interpretation: the number of arrests per year of age.* That is an intuitive predictor of short time to the next arrest: if an individual has many arrests per year, the time to the next arrest might be short.

But if `prio` is strictly positive, then `age/prio` is simply the inverse of `prio/age` and there's no reason to exclude it. The `age/prio` measure would be the years between arrests; a short prior time between arrests might predict a short time to the next arrest. Having the expected sign of a coefficient that's the same as or opposite to that of another related predictor, like `interactions_with_police`, isn't a theoretical problem.

There might be a practical question about which direction of the ratio gives a better linear fit to log-hazard and thus be more suitable for a survival model. If both ratios are defined, however, then there's no *theoretical* reason to prefer one over the other.

Is using `prio/age` more or less useful than using both `age` and `prio` as separate predictors? If one includes both `age` and `prio` as separate predictors, should there also be some type of interaction term between them? A `prio/age` predictor, after all, is equivalent to an interaction term between `prio` and `1/age`. I don't know that one can say in general what's most useful. It depends on the subject matter.

There is an art to doing regression modeling, guided by statistical principles and understanding of the subject matter. Frank Harrell's [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) and [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) provide extensive guidance.

Yes, there is something to be said for including as many predictors as possible, provided you avoid overfitting. If it's possible to combine predictors usefully based on subject-matter knowledge, without looking at the outcomes, you could effectively include even more. If you are willing to use penalization in your modeling, like ridge regression, there's little limit to the number of original predictors you might consider.

So if you take such steps to avoid overfitting, there's no theoretical problem with including large numbers of predictors in a model. Predictors that "make sense" from the perspective of the subject matter are certainly to be preferred in terms of model interpretability. If such predictors happen to be ratios, there's no problem with including them.

---

*You might want to adjust `age` to the number of years during which an individual was subject to arrest, but the general principle holds.